# "They perform" vs. "they are performed" in specific context

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-usage

> Our experiments include simulated falls by several subjects. They 
>   **perform** in a user-independent setting, where, for each test  video,
>   the subject appearing in the test video does not appear in any  of the
>   training data used to detect falls in that video.

In the above sentence, is the usage of *perform* correct, or should I use "they are performed" instead?

Comment: You're right, this is not correct. It should be "were performed" or "have been performed" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an awkward sentence. As written, you expect *They* to refer to the falls rather than the performers, because that's the head of the precedent noun phrase; but the author obviously intends *they* to refer to the performing *subjects*.

The ambiguity might be avoided with rewriting:

> Our experiments include simulated falls by several subjects, who perform in a user-independent setting: that is, the subject who falls in each test video does not appear in any of the training data used to detect falls in that video.